# Are there official rules for touch rugby?

Tags: touch-rugby

Touch rugby is a sport widely played in New Zealand and Australia, similar to rugby league except the main difference is that the person with the ball is touched instead of tackled.

To the best of my knowledge (mine, and Google's), there is no official rules for touch rugby, or even a touch rugby federation or similar.

This is a big problem in games at school, where technical points get brought up and no-one knows how to handle this.

**Are there official rules for touch rugby**? If so, where can I find them and who were they made by?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official rules for Touch Football, a rugby league derivative, are available from the "[Rules and Policies](http://www.touchfootball.com.au/index.php?id=1273)" section of the Touch Football Australia website. As of February 2016, the 7th Edition of the Rules ("reprinted 2007") is current.

However, the document explicitly encourage competitions to vary the rules under which the game is played; from the Foreword:

> There is no compulsion for any affiliate of the [Australian Touch Association] to follow these Rules at their local or park level competitions. In fact the ATA encourages Affiliates to set varying features in the rules of their competition so that the player can experience a wide variety of enjoyment from the game.

but they may still give you a basis on which to form your competition's rule set.